# How to build an iOS4 app that will also run on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, deployment

I'm trying to build an iOS4 app (not universal) that will also run in compatibility mode on the iPad.  So I set the Deployment Target to 3.2 and the Device Family to iPhone.

This works fine in adhoc builds, but when I try to upload it the the store, Application Loader complains: “This bundle is invalid. An application targeting the iPhone device family may not require a iOS Deployment Target 3.2, which is an iPad-only OS”.

What?  Are my only choices to set the Deployment Target to 4.0 and not run at all on the iPad, or set it to 3.1.x and build/test the app for a platform I don't want to support, that Apple doesn't even ship an SDK for any more?  Am I missing something?

Comment: You could file a bug with Apple...

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Targeted Device Family" to iPhone/iPad

Comment: I don't want to support a native iPad app, I just want to be able to run in compatibility mode.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck there. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

New firmwares support compatibility on older ones. For example: 3.1.x apps are compatible with 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, etc.
My guess is set it up as an iOS4 app. Also remember there are some functions on iPad that do not work on iPhone and viceversa. So your app could still crash.

Comment: I realize that.  I'm trying to avoid the hassle of writing conditional code and testing on the 3.1.x platform (MPMoviePlayerController workarounds being a perfect example).  I know my app is backward-compatible with the 3.2 API, and I just want to be able to run it in compatibility mode on the iPad.